# Z3 infinite loop from KLEE

Tags: z3, klee

I have a modified version of KLEE and an essentially simple query
like

```
(assert (= 173 (str.len "OREN"))) (meant to be false).
```

When I invoke the Z3 solver I get stuck in an infinite loop
(haven't waited forever though :]) inside the following while statement in
z3/src/ast/rewriter/rewriter_def.h:

```
while (!frame_stack().empty())
```

I've posted it as a potential bug in [GitHub/Z3Prover/z3/issues](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1359)
but I'm not at all sure it is indeed a bug. Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I see the github issue was resolved. Can you post an answer here for others?

Comment: You can also accept your own answer to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer in [GitHub/Z3Prover/z3/issues](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1359):

> KLEE uses the **C API** but uses **wrapper classes** to correctly do reference counting.

However what I did back at the time was:

> called the Z3 C API **without** using KLEE's wrapper class: **Z3ASTHandle**

That made things go (very) wrong ...